# Xproc p:http-request dynamic href URI

Tags: xproc

My Calabash xproc pipeline uses p:http-request to fire a GET request. The server requires authentication, so I use a c:request with username / password / auth-method attributes. I am struggling with the question how to fill the href attribute of c:request dynamically.

Calabash doesn't seem to like:

```
<c:request method="GET" href="{$href}" username="username" password="password" auth-method="basic" detailed="false"/>
```

This is not a big surprise, because setting href dynamically would not work on p:load either. But in the latter case, adding a p:with-option child helps. With c:request, it doesn't.

So this makes me wonder if there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

XProc 1.0 does not support attribute value templates. There is, however, the optional but very useful [p:template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc-template/) step (which Calabash supports as far as I know) - the [Introduction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc-template/#introduction) section covers precisely your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it describes exactly my problem. However, I am not sure if p:template is much clearer / cleaner than rolling your own XProc step in a custom library (which is what I did).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the solution here is to dynamically construct the c:request element + attributes.

A working example looks like this:

```
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">
  <p:input port="source">
    <p:inline>
      <c:request method="GET" username="username" password="password" auth-method="basic"/>
    </p:inline>
  </p:input>
  <p:output port="result"/>

  <p:option name="area" select="'testvalue1'"/>
  <p:option name="work" select="'testvalue2'"/>

  <p:add-attribute match="/c:request" attribute-name="href">
    <p:with-option name="attribute-value" select="concat('http://localhost:8181/exist/rest/db/OEP/code/test/testGet.xql?area=', $area, '&amp;work=', $work)"/>
  </p:add-attribute>

  <p:http-request/>
</p:declare-step>
```

I would still be interested in a better way because this just doesn't seem right :-(